# What is this mark?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Little `~` style squiglly lines have started appearing in a variety of my `.js` files in random places like this:

[image]

Hovering this little mark shows the following message:
[image]

Sometimes it shows at the start of a `module.exports` line, sometimes at a `require` statement, and sometimes on every single line in the file - it is really annoying.

Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: FWIW, when hovering the line of code in question I also get a hint (yellow lightbulb) which when clicked prompts me to "Convert to ES6 module".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a feature that is built-in to Visual Studio Code.

You can turn it off by setting `javascript.suggestionActions.enabled` to `false` in your User Settings.